# How can I remove an apple id

Tags: apple-id

I can't get my ex husbands apple id out of the family  ipad. Now I have a ton of apps to update and he won't give our kids his password to update them.

Comment: Do you want to wipe the iPad and start over or sync it to a computer to get a partial or full backup or do you want to clean the ex's apps one by one?

Answer (score 1):

The easy and sure way to start over is to restore the device to factory defaults and wipe everything away. If you don't want that, you'll have to learn how the settings app uses AppleID and decide which ones you want to delete from the device and which you can live with on the device.